# R string to object

Tags: r

I am trying to return the value of the object instead of TRUE or FALSE, though I am struggling: so far I have a list of data, I can call that list which returns the values, fine. I also want to return the values of the list which are > 0. I dont just want True or FALSE. I then want to sum the values above zero....

```
with_Gain = (Count_Return1 > 0)
get("with_Gain")
```

Please advise, many thanks

Comment: what does the code you've provided return?  what would you like it to return?  can you provide a complete example with input and desired output?

Comment: Justin-Just brings up a list of TRUE and FALSE, which is essentially correct-though I want the value of the TRUE.

Comment: Josh-this just returns TRUE and FALSE...

Comment: `Count_Return1[Count_Return1 > 0]` will return the values > 0.

Comment: Arun-thats perfect, what I needed-you read the question...

Comment: Bit unnecessary to mark me down on this..

Comment: Please note that @user1317221's answer, which you called 'just indexing' does exactly the same thing as Arun's. Try both with some sample data to see that!

Comment: Josh-just didnt work seamless for me I'm afraid..mark me down again if you wish

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `which()`.

```
Count_Return1 <- c(3,2,-1)

Count_Return1[which(Count_Return1 > 0)]
 #[1] 3 2 
 #returns the values above 0
```

`which()` not really needed here `Count_Return1[Count_Return1 > 0]` will do the same job.

But if you want the index not the value then use:

```
which(Count_Return1 > 0)
#[1] 1 2 
#returns the index for the values above 0
```

Comment: Ben-bit of an unwarranted comment.

Comment: thanks @JoshO'Brien yeah I had that in the `#comments` maybe I should make them clearer

Comment: user-appreciate the efforts, though this is just indexing.

Comment: not sure what you mean by *"just indexing"*. This does what you ask in your question. perhaps as suggested above you should provide what `Count_Return1` looks like and an expected output...

Answer (score 0):

You can shift the left parenthesis like this :

```
(with_Gain = Count_Return1 > 0)
[1] TRUE
```

Of course this assumes that you have already defined Count_Return1 ..

**EDIT**

To get the values of the object , you do something like

```
   Count_Return1[Count_Return1 > 0]
```

and to get the index of the condition

```
   which(Count_Return1 > 0)
```

For example :

```
set.seed(1234)
> Count_Return1 <- sample(c(-1,1),10,rep=T)
> Count_Return1[Count_Return1 > 0]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> Count_Return1 > 0
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```